# Any alternative way for trait to implement its parent trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I am building a Raft consensus algorithm middleware for Rust with a similar architecture to [copycat](http://atomix.io/copycat/). I wrote a macro for developers to define a scheme for commands. The macro generates a trait `A` with a `dispatch` function for user defined commands, which requires the developer to implement a struct for its behavior and an encoder/decoder which is irrelevant to this topic.

The trait objects register with a `Server` object to make it work. Because trait `A` is dynamically generated, I have to define another trait `B` as parent trait for `A`. `Server` works with `B` to invoke the `dispatch` function defined in `A`.

I tried different combination but none of them works.

```
trait B {
    fn dispatch(&mut self, fn_id: u64) -> Vec<u8>;
}

// macro generated trait
trait A: B {
    fn a(&self) -> Vec<u8>;
    fn b(&self) -> Vec<u8>;
    fn dispatch(&mut self, fn_id: u64) -> Vec<u8> {
        match fn_id {
            1 => a(),
            2 => b(),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `dispatch` function in `A` will not implement `dispatch` in `B`. When I implement the structure for `A`, the compiler still asked to implement `dispatch` for `B`.

I also tried to move `dispatch` in trait `B` to another trait as the parent trait for `B`, but the trait cannot implement for `A`.

I have also reviewed https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1024. It seems the issue is open but have been ditched. Is there any alternative way to make this pattern work?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why not just implement `B` at the same time you are expanding the macro that creates the trait `A`?

Comment: @Shepmaster because there will be more traits like A generated by the macro the server need a common trait to invoke dispatch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `B` to be a supertrait of `A` at all.  You can instead add a blanket implementation of `B` for any `T: A`.  I think this closer to the intent.

Paraphrasing the Rust code:

```
trait A: B {
```

"You can implement `A`, but only if you've implemented `B`."

```
trait A {
    //...
}
impl<T: A> B for T {
```

"If you implement `A`, here's a free implementation of `B`."

Here's the full version:

```
trait B {
    fn dispatch(&mut self, fn_id: u64) -> Vec<u8>;
}

// macro generated trait
trait A {
    fn a(&self) -> Vec<u8>;  // added &self
    fn b(&self) -> Vec<u8>;
}

impl<T: A> B for T {
    fn dispatch(&mut self, fn_id: u64) -> Vec<u8> {
        match fn_id {
            1 => self.a(),
            2 => self.b(),
            _ => panic!(),   // Needed so that match cases are exhaustive
        }
    }
}

struct S {}

impl A for S {
    fn a(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    fn b(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8645ebbbb4e2bc90ba1c0ea267244a03&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But what if there is another function in `B` like `foo` I have update in the question which it should be implement by developers for `S`?

Comment: Add `foo` to `A` for the developer to implement, and have the generated `B` impl call that?

Comment: In this case the server that looking for `B` can't see it

Comment: I think that these should be a new question rather than changes to the original one.

Comment: I am sorry for this. I will close this question and open a new one